# Unique Identifier for Lightning-input inside custom Data table

Tags: lightning-datatable, pageblocktable, datatable, table

I have a custom data table and I wish to validate Desired_quantity for each row but I'm having trouble with creating a unique class for lightning-input component and fetching it using queryselector.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
          <template for:each={selected} for:item="select" >
              <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={select.id}>
                 <td>
                    <div class="slds-truncate">{select.Name}</div>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    <div class="slds-truncate">{select.Brand}</div>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                   <div class="slds-truncate">{select.MRP}</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                 <div class="slds-truncate">{select.Stock}</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                 <div class="slds-truncate">
                    <div class="slds-m-bottom_small">
                    <lightning-input
                       class=".inp1"
                       type="number"
                       name={select.id}
                       value={select.Desired_quantity}
                       label="Product Quantity"
                       onchange={updateQuantity}
                       ></lightning-input>
                 </div>
              </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                 <div class="slds-truncate">
                    <lightning-button variant="destructive"
                    label="Remove" 
                    title="Destructive action"
                    name={select.id}
                    onclick={remove} 
                    class="slds-m-left_x-small">
        </lightning-button></div>
                </td>
              </tr>
           </template>
```

JS

```
updateQuantity(event){

    var inputCmp = this.template.querySelector(".inp1");

    var index = 0;

    for(var i of this.selected){
        if(event.target.name==i.id){
            break;
        }
        index++;
    }


    if(event.target.value < this.selected[index].Stock){
        this.selected[index].Desired_quantity = event.targe.value;
        inputCmp.setCustomValidity("");
    }
    else{
        inputCmp.setCustomValidity("error");
    }

    //console.log("updated selected products:=>" + JSON.stringify(this.selected));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<template for:each={selected} for:item="select" for:index="index" >
....
 <lightning-input
                       data-target-id={index}
                       type="number"
                       name={select.id}
                       value={select.Desired_quantity}
                       label="Product Quantity"
                       onchange={updateQuantity}
                       ></lightning-input>
</template>
```

JS

```
updateQuantity(event){

var index = event.target.dataset.targetId;
var inputfield=this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-input")[index];

if(event.target.value < this.selected[index].Stock){
        this.selected.Desired_quantity = event.target.value;
        inputfield.setCustomValidity("");
    }
    else{
        inputfield.setCustomValidity("error");
    }
}
```

if you have lightning input outside the table in that case

```
 <lightning-input
                       data-target-id={index}
                       type="number"
                       class="test"
                       name={select.id}
                       value={select.Desired_quantity}
                       label="Product Quantity"
                       onchange={updateQuantity}
                       ></lightning-input>
```

and in JS just replace lightning input with class name

```
var inputfield=this.template.querySelectorAll(".test");
```

Comment: not working as I already had another lightning-input outside of the table and when the code is like var inputfield=this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-input")[1]; it does not update the value.

Comment: @J.rosnovski i have updated the answer

Comment: var inputfield=this.template.querySelectorAll(".test");
        console.log("val===" + inputfield.value);
        var index = event.target.dataset.targetId;
        console.log("index===" + index); 
first console gives output undefined and second output gives correct output according to the loop.

Comment: @yashasvi2 yes that is correct why do you need inputfield.value you can just use event.targe.value;

Comment: works what I did was var index = event.target.dataset.targetId;var inputfield=this.template.querySelectorAll(".test")[index]; and then it works for every row .Thanks